# Multiple inserts and updates in on SQL

Tags: sql, database, performance, oracle

Hi I am currently trying to do multiple updates and inserts in one sql.

I have a table where i load data which has the following columns:

- Rownumber
- Start date
- End date
- Other data columns

This table is a historical table view of data. The row number is the number of rows 1 to number records for a given start and end period. Meaning if it contains 100 records for 1980 to end of time it has 1 to 100 for that period.

If say record 3 has been deleted from 1st april 2014 to end of time then all records after record number 3 need to have their rownumber decreased by one to ensure the rownumber has no gaps. Futhermore this in turn means we need to split all records after so that when you look at the table before april 1st 2014 you see 100 rows. But any time after you see the 99 rows. This essentially means updating the end times of the records 4-100 to be 31 march 2014 and a inserting new record from 1st of april 2014 till the end of time inserted which is a copy ie the data is the same with a rownumber decrememnted by 1.

Now I want to avoid having to do many individual updates and inserts. Ie 90+ x  2 of each. Im hoping theres a smart way todo this via a single sql or less than 90 or so.

I was thinking along the lines of

```
Update table set rownumber=rownumber -1 where rownumber > 3 (Deleted rownumber)
```

of course this example does not handle the splitting of the time and doing the inserts

Im running under oracle 11g.
I cant change the table structure either I have to keep row number consistent and without gaps within a time period. Also any updates or inserts are on this one table.

Any advice tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd say screw rownumber update, just number them at display time.

Comment: The rownumber is something that cannot be ignored, there are other programs accessing this table that rely upon the rownumber. This is out of my control and something I cannot change unfortunately otherwise the problem would not be so difficult.

Comment: You need a trigger on insert, update and delete that'll do your row renumbering, this should take 1 to 2 update statement runs per trigger. Sorry can't help further, because I don't have experience in writing triggers that can do recursion.

Comment: Again as I said I cannot modify this table.

Comment: As I understand you, you've said you can't alter the table's structure, not update its contents. A trigger does not alter the table's structure, it's an action SQL Server performs in response on a certain request, be it insert, update or select, depending on DBA's needs.

Comment: I solved it, I was able to build a query to update the rownumber as I thought above. To handle the splitting of records ie update of existing and insert of new to do the split. I did just that. So in the case a row change spans a time I do 3 SQL queries. All works great and its a lot quicker than doing individual queries for each row.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad programming practice to store the rownum in the table..
instead of storing it..update your table structure to remove the rownum column and where ever u need to retrieve it just add the pseudo column name rownum.
so

```
select rownum, <column list> from <table name>
```

will do the same job. and you will not need to update each time.

untill and unless u specifically need the rownum column stored, dont create a column for it.

Please specify use case where you would need the rownum column stored..??

then accordingly i can help you.

***Edit after comment from user:***

Use the following statement for the rownum update:

```
update table t1 set rownum_col=(select rn from (select rownum rn, pk1 , pk2 from table ) t2 where t1.pk1=t2.pk1 and t1.pk2=t2.pk2);
```

Comment: As I said I cannot modify the table structure, this is not mine to control. This is one of the restrictions. The row number is used on other parts of the system that access this table. Again something I do not control

Comment: Thanks for that but its still not handling the splitting of the records via time, so doing the insert where needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the part about splitting up the rows, but to do a sequential numbering of all rows you can use something like this:

```
merge into the_table
using
(
   select rowid as rid,
          row_number() over (order by start_date) as new_rownumber
   from the_table
) t on (t.rid = the_table.rowid) 
when matched then update 
  set rownumber = new_rownumber;
```

If the rownumber is not "global" over the complete table, you need to add a `partition by` clause to the window function to restart the numbering for the different "blocks" of data.

Comment: Consider the following, you have a record in the table that starts from 1/1/1980 to end of time. If this record is then modified in a diff period, say 1/4/2014, the original record in the DB must keep its data as it was but we need to change this records end time to be -1 sec less than 1/4/2014. The new change needs to be then inserted as a new record from 1st April 2014 to end of time. Effectively splitting the original record into two records. I want to avoid doing single updates and single inserts, Im hoping to do it in a more efficient SQL query